Do you know how to model this round object?
Do you know how to model this? The small screws are not important to me.


Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"


You can start with a cylinder that has a beveled top and then use a boolean modifier with an object like this to cut the holes out of it

Thank you!!!!!!!
